# Generic Term for Derivative of a Conceptual System

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the generic term for a noun that forms part of the main vocabulary of a conceptual system?

For example:

- A number is a **derivative** of arithmetic.
- A word is a **derivative** of language.
- An atom is a **derivative** of chemistry.
- A border is a **derivative** of map.

I'm looking for the most appropriate replacement for the word 'derivative' above. Preferably a single word!

Comment: Component? Perhaps... Element... though that could be confusing in your chemistry example.

Comment: I'd say "element" if it weren't for the chemistry example.  *Component,* perhaps?

Comment: @phoog HA HA HA HA HA We said the same thing.

Comment: @Catija great minds...

Comment: I'd go with *term of art*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps *[constituent](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/constituent)* (as a noun)

> a component part; ingredient

*Collins*

Similarly, *[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituent)*

> an essential part :  component, element

Answer (score 0):

> A word is an **aspect** of language.
>
> An atom is an **element** of chemistry.
>
> A number is a **factor** of arithmetic.
>
> A derivative is a **component** of mathematics.
>
> A border is a **facet** of a map.

From Oxford:

> Facet /ˈfasət/
>
> **noun**
>
> 1.1 A particular aspect or feature of something

Comment: I disagree strongly with element, factor, and facet in those particular uses. "element" has a specific meaning in Chemistry and there is no element "atom".  Similarly, a "factor" is a mathematical term and it is inappropriate to use it here.  And I just don't agree with the use of facet, so... yeah.

Comment: @Catija Somebody's not a fan of the puns

Comment: Why would you make puns when someone's asking a legitimate question and wanting help? I know people like to have fun here but it's not funny to give people bad information because you think it's a joke.